# What should I do about a hole close to a plug that is too wide?

Tags: walls, hole, spackling-paste

I used spacking to fill a hole that is like really wide, but not that lengthy.  I painted it, then put more spacking on the hole. The hole is still noticeable. So like if I just keep putting more spacking, will it sooner or later look noramlish?

Answer (score 2):

Muralo's *Spackle™* shrinks as it dries. If you keep applying thin layers and letting them dry, you will eventually achieve a flat surface. If the Spackle is proud of the surrounding surface you should be able to sand it flat.